# A word or phrase for a brief, unplanned romantic interaction

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a scene in which two characters have a bit of a heated snog in a broom cupboard. Neither is intending to take it any further. What word or phrase would best fit this type of situation? I considered 'quickie' and checked its synonyms, but that noun is usually associated with sex and there's none of that in this particular interaction. Besides, I'm searching for something more formal, either euphemistic or honest, but definitely polite, as opposed to something vulgar and informal.

An example sentence would be: 'She fixed her hair and quickly smoothed the wrinkles from her dress to hide the evidence of their [insert word/phrase.]'

Thanks.

Comment: In the US, we never snog, though we do have *make-out sessions*.

Comment: Are you looking for something colloquial or formal, euphemistic or honest, vulgar or polite? And US, UK, or elsewhere? There are a lot of words that might apply, some very vague, some very exact.

Comment: Thanks, @StuartF. I've edited my original question. I don't particularly mind whether the word/phrase is euphemistic or honest, but I would definitely prefer something formal and polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider :

[tete-a-tete](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=tete-a-tete) :
Involving two persons; intimately private
Without the intrusion of a third person; in intimate privacy

[tête-à-tête](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/t%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-t%C3%AAte) :
a private conversation between two persons

Alternatives :

romantic brush (brush == Momentary contact)
unplanned intimacy (intimacy == Warm friendship or sexual relationship)
covert coquetry (coquetry == Playful behaviour intended to arouse sexual interest)
amatory indulgence (indulgence == Indulging or gratifying a desire)

These all fit into your Sentence in ".... hide evidence of their [Insert word here] ...." & suit the Situation.

Possibilities are there in Mixing & Matching these words !

Answer (score 1):

**Dalliance** would be a good fit here, indicating casual physical relationship that is short and not serious. It's not restricted to a single encounter, but it does carry the connotation that it's not a long-term relationship. The word is not used very commonly and has a bit of a polite air to it. A more casual and less polite term would be to call it a **hookup**, which also indicates a brief physical encounter. Neither term is particularly specific about the extent of the physical relationship, and could feasibly refer to anything from kissing to sex.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **indiscretion** in the sense of:

> an act at variance with the accepted morality of a society

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indiscretion

Answer (score 0):

**Fling** ([FARLEX](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fling)) A brief, casual sexual or romantic relationship.

**Affairette** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affairette#English)) A brief romantic relationship, especially with someone who is in a relationship with another person, or not one's regular partner.